# OpenOffice Macro - How to append text to "Author" field

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, openoffice

currently I have an OO macro that processes a document and then sets the "Author" by using:

```
oDoc.getDocumentProperties().Author = cAuthor
```

However that replaces any existing text in that field, I would like to be able to just append the new text to the "Author" field instead of overwriting the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Save the current author value to a string variable. Then add what you want to the end of the string variable. Finally, save the new author property. Here is a VBA example:

```
Sub AppendAuthor()
    Dim cAuthor As String
    cAuthor = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.wdPropertyAuthor) & chr(32) & "New Author"
    ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.wdPropertyAuthor) = cAuthor
    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.wdPropertyAuthor)
End Sub
```